# How to combine Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> with Observable<OnCheckedChangeEvent>?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm learning RxJava using the RxAndroid library, while using Retrofit to do networking, and RetroLambda to use Java8 lambdas.

The app I wish to build has the following functionality:

- Allow user to type a query to the Wikipedia API
- Wait 1 second after typing until a network call is done
- Show progress indicator when the app is 'busy' fetching result
- The progress indicator starts immediately after typing, not after 1 second, and finishes when a result or error is received

I have it working like such:

```
// emit when text is changed
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> textStream = WidgetObservable.text(mEditText);
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> debouncedStream = textStream.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Unchecked assignment

// start activity indicator immediately
textStream
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(s -> mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));

debouncedStream
        .map(t -> wikiService.search(t.text().toString())) // query wikipedia
        .map(Object::toString)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(s -> {
            mTextView.setText(s == null ? "Error" : s);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
```

Now, I wish to add a new widget, to allow my wikipedia query to use another language. For now, I'll settle on a Switch, either "en" or "nl" as prefix for the wikipedia url.

[image: GUI before user interacts with it]

So I make a new Observable from the Switch, it emits `OnCheckedChangeEvent`s.

My thinking is, I need to combine this Observable with the `textStream`.

When the switch is flipped basically the same functionality should be run, but not quite. The current running query (if at all running) becomes obsolete, since the url-prefix will change. It should wait another 1 second, and then start a new network call.

Obviously the following does not work:

```
// emit when Switch is flipped
Observable<OnCheckedChangeEvent> languageSwitchStream = WidgetObservable.input(mLanguageSwitch);

// emit when text is changed
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> textStream = WidgetObservable.text(mEditText);

// combine these 2, but they are using different types
Observable uiChangeStream = Observable.merge(textStream, languageSwitchStream);

Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> debouncedStream = uiChangeStream.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Unchecked assignment
```

I cannot just merge the `textStream` and `languageSwitchStream`.

So the question becomes: how should I approach this, using proper Rx?

== SOLUTION ==========================

```
// emit when Switch is flipped
Observable<OnCheckedChangeEvent> languageSwitchStream =
        WidgetObservable
                .input(mLanguageSwitch)
                .startWith(new OnCheckedChangeEvent() {
                    @Override
                    public CompoundButton view() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean value() {
                        return mLanguageSwitch.isChecked();
                    }
                });

// emit when text is changed
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> textStream = WidgetObservable.text(mEditText);

Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> uiChangeStream = Observable
        .combineLatest(
                textStream,
                languageSwitchStream,
                (text, switchValue) -> text);

uiChangeStream
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(s -> mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));

uiChangeStream
        .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(t -> wikiService.search(t.text().toString())) // query wikipedia
        .map(Object::toString)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(s -> {
            mTextView.setText(s == null ? "Error" : s);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
```

Expanding upon the approved answer, I added a `.startsWith()` to the
Switch's Observable, otherwise it will keep waiting for it to be flipped, before emitting a value.

Comment: Does it have to use RX ? Because it looks like you just need a CheckListener to replace wikiService.

Comment: Why specifically are you waiting 1 second before making the network request.  How did you come up with this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CombineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) and do something like this:

```
Observable<SearchParams> uiChangeStream = Observable.combineLatest(
    textStream, 
    languageSwitchStream,
    (text, switch) -> /* extract info from each and return search params */)
.map(searchParams -> wikiService.search(searchParams);
```

`combineLatest()` will re-emit the last value from the other Observable when one Observable emits a new value.

Comment: Could the `zip` operator be useful here as well?